# How to model user creating object model then used to create many instances

Tags: java, spring

Forgive the lack of knowledge, I'm experimenting with Spring for the first time and writing a simple workout tracker. The use case is

- User creates an exercise

  - Sets name, type of exercise (cardio or weight lifting) and if weight lifting, sets the muscle group worked
- As user works out, he adds instances of the exercise.  (Bench Pressed on 10/27 with weight lifted)

I'm stuck on how to model this using Spring.  I currently have an Exercise POJO which looks like

```
public class Exercise {

private int id;
private String name;
private List<MuscleGroup> muscleGroups;
private String note;
private Date performDate;

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the note
 */
public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

/**
 * @param note the note to set
 */
public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}

/**
 * @return the performDate
 */
public Date getPerformDate() {
    return performDate;
}

/**
 * @param performDate the performDate to set
 */
public void setPerformDate(Date performDate) {
    this.performDate = performDate;
}

/**
 * @return the muscleGroups
 */
public List<MuscleGroup> getMuscleGroups() {
    return muscleGroups;
}

/**
 * @param muscleGroups the muscleGroups to set
 */
public void setMuscleGroups(List<MuscleGroup> muscleGroups) {
    this.muscleGroups = muscleGroups;
}
}
```

The weight lifting POJO extends Exercise and looks like

```
public class WeightExercise extends Exercise{

private List<WeightSet> sets;

/**
 * @return the sets
 */
public List<WeightSet> getSets() {
    return sets;
}

/**
 * @param sets the sets to set
 */
public void setSets(List<WeightSet> sets) {
    this.sets = sets;
}
}
```

If the user could supply any name and muscle group, this would be trivial, but I'd like to allow the user to create the Exercise type first such as Bench Press which works the chest muscle group and is of type WeightExercise.  Then on Day 1, they would add Bench Press from a list of exercises they've created, add sets/reps with that date and save (likely to a Database). Two days later they might do the same thing, with different sets/reps and date but with the same exercise.

How does one model this using Spring?  Surely I don't create a BenchPress class, Squat class, etc, as they'll all have the same fields/methods just different values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that may work well for the model you want.

```
public interface Exercise {
    String getName();
    List<String> getMuscleGroups();
    ...
}

public class BenchPress {
    public String getName() {
        return "bench press";
    }

    List<String> getMuscleGroups () {
        List<String> result;

        result = new List<String>();
        result.add("chest");

        return result;
    }
}
```

There is much left out and some improvements could be made, but I believe this shows a good way to avoid having members in sub-classes only distinguished by value.  An abstract base class is another good approach, especially if there are common fields (like, perhaps, ID).

Comment: Thanks. I've considered this, but it leaves me with two problems. The first is that I'd like the user to be able to create an exercise named bench press (not a java create in the sense of new, but by passing in the name "Bench Press".  The second is that I'd have a bunch of exercise classes ("BenchPress", "Squat", "DeadLift", etc that would all have the same implementation.